# Problems with Math.Truncate(num)

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, double

as the question suggests (more of a statement sorry) I'm having problems using math.truncate in C#. What I'm trying to do is say when the decimal of a number divided by 50 is equal to 0.4 do this, as such:

```
double temp2 = 170;    
temp2 = temp2 / 50;   //this equals 3.4
temp2 -= Math.Truncate(temp2);
if (temp2 == 0.4)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}
```

However when I try to do this it's not working for me and I'm unsure why it's not working, would I be able to get someone to shed some light on this and put me in the right direction please?

Comment: `0.4` cannot be represented exactly, it's actually `0.4000000059604645`. That's why `==` wouldn't work.

Comment: Also note that you can use `temp = temp % 1.0` or even `temp %= 1.0` to obtain the fractional part of a number a bit more cleanly than truncating. This works for `decimal` too, `temp %= 1.0m`.

Comment: 170/50 != 3.4 because there is no such binary FP number

Answer (score 4):

`single` and `double` are binary floating-point types. That means they cannot exactly represent many decimal values (like 0.4). This can lead to subtle round-off errors, so comparing two `double` values that logically *should* represent the same value can lead to unexpected results.

This can be empirically be verified using the [`DoubleToInt64Bits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.doubletoint64bits.aspx) method:

```
BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(temp2); // 4600877379321698712
BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(0.4);   // 4600877379321698714
```

Change it to `decimal` and you'll get the result you expect:

```
decimal temp2 = 170;    
temp2 = temp2 / 50;   //this equals 3.4
temp2 -= Math.Truncate(temp2);
if (temp2 == 0.4m)    // the m creates a decimal constant
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't think it mattered. Thanks a lot (: working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

When you subtract away the most significant part of a floating-point number, because the subtraction result has a smaller magnitude compared to the minuend, a lot of extra "artificial" precision exists in that result. And because the original number was not exactly represented (as is almost always the case with binary floating-point), that extra precision looks like garbage.

To take a more extreme example (which is the same in principle):

```
double x = 987654321098.4 - 987654321098.0;
// x becomes 0.4000244140625
```

Here the order of magnitude changed very much. In the original example:

```
3.4 - 3.0
```

the result, approx. `0.4`, is stil less then one eighth of approx. `3.4`, so three extra bits of precision there.